# OPC communication with Python

Tags: python, opc

I am quite new with OPC and Python so be patient :) I have an HART USB modem connected to a sensor communicating with HART standard.(HART is seen as an OPC item).
I would like to establish a communication with Python to retrieve for example the ID and the measured values (all HART general function).

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using an OPC DA server?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea.. I was trying to use opcua

Comment: Your question attracts answerers who misunderstand it as requesting recommendations for libraries/tools, which would be off-topic. Please [edit] to avoid that impression, by making more obvious what programming you want help with. If you cannot you might want to delete your post.